# pytorch MultiheadAttention - when and where can one use weights (the second output)?

Tags: pytorch, attention-model

I've read through a few `MultiheadAttention` tutorials now, and I consistently see the weights return value being ignored, ie:

```py
x, _ = myattention(q,k,v)
```

I've also seen a [`need_weights`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html#torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.forward) parameter that can be used to omit the second output.

This got me curious about where/when the weights are useful. Is there a scenario where the weights can be used along with, or instead of, the output in a forward pass?

Comment: There are many instances where you need to return the attention maps in order to perform some visualizations or additional computation / regularizations depending on the method used.

Comment: Do you know of any OSS repos or papers that show this being done? I couldn't find any good examples on the official pytorch site. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "OSS", but for instance here is a CVPR'22 paper which leverages attentions maps in transformer networks: ***Learning Affinity from Attention: End-to-End Weakly-Supervised Semantic Segmentation with Transformers***

Comment: Sorry, I meant "open source software". This paper is great, it answers my question, thanks for it!